# Firebase 2.0 AngularJS Support

Tags: firebase

With the new Firebase released today at Google IO 2016.  I was wondering if/when AngularFire will be supported on the updated version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update is [on it's way](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/pull/717) it should be just a day or two out once we're confident everything is good to go :)